# Firebase Analytics preventing proper use of dynamic link

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm running in trouble here with Firebase.
The code is in flutter, I am testing in iOS
It's all going well, but when I try to get the dynamic link sent from:

```
auth.sendSignInWithEmailLink(parameters);
```

I get a debug message:

```
[Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {
    amv = 16;
    apn = "com.myproject.app";
    ibi = "com.myproject.app";
    ifl = "https://myproject-com.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXX&mode=signIn&oobCode=XXXXXX&continueUrl=https://myproject-com.firebaseapp.com/email123&lang=en";
    link = "https://myproject-com.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey=XXXXXXX&mode=signIn&oobCode=XXXXXX&continueUrl=https://myproject-com.firebaseapp.com/email123&lang=en";
}

where I changed my project name to "myproject" and put XXX inplace of apiKey/oobcode
```

and then, when I try to get the dynamic link with my app

```
final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
```

data is null.
So I am guessing Firebase Analytics is processing it and "killing" the dynamic link before my app can parse it.

Anyone managed to go through this?

Comment: As I continue to research this, I created a dynamic link in Firebase (console), and tried it in my app. It also does not work, and now Firebase replies

2020-08-02 13:28:50.940975-0700 Project[4224:883558] 6.29.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023000] Deep Link Web URL query is empty

Comment: the short link comes out as empty. The long link behaves exactly as the email link - 
Analytics says deep link does not contain valid required params. And passes on Null to my handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.
It is not that Firebase Analytics was "consuming" and killing the deep link.
The thing is that in iOS still today there is a delay the link and the state cycle...
https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-firebase-dynamic-link-6f1b79278ce0

This link explains it, problem 2 in the blog post.
Solved. I can still use analytics in Firebase.
It is impossible to remove analytics btw, you can only disable it.